# Is it possible to make these regex shorter?

Tags: ruby, regex, optimization

As the topic suggest, is it possible to make these regex shorter? I am are using Ruby 1.9.3

```
/\n\s+(\w{0,3})[\s&&[^\n]\S]+?([\d\.]+)[\S\s&&[^\n]]+?([\d\.]+)/
```

and this

```
/\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+-*\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+/
```

Thanks!

Comment: Retrieves the three first columns  from here www.ida.liu.se/~TDP007/material/seminarie2/weather.txt

Comment: If it works, why do you want to shorten it?

Comment: I believe that `[\s&&[^\n]\S]` could be replaced with `[^\n]` although I don't know enough about ruby character classes to say for sure. (I believe that `[\s&&[^\n]\S]` means "any whitespace or non-whitespace character except a newline", which can be written as `[^\n]`)

Comment: Does `&&` have any special meaning in Ruby Regex?

Comment: @inhan - I believe it is used to join two character classes.

Comment: They're the same expression?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I want to learn :)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 So that's the reason why `[\s&&[^\n]\S]` makes sense..? Because normally a character group inside another one wouldn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @LeeJarvis Derp.. Fixed!

Comment: @inhan - `&&` actually performs an intersection, not a join (see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html). So my original comment was not exactly correct. `[\s&&[^\n]\S]` actually means "the character is a whitespace char AND it is (not a newline OR non-whitespace character)".

Comment: That works! Any further tips?

Comment: I am not sure if there are more data, but if it is only that file, you can process by hand, then read the file line by line and split by space.

Answer (score 2):

- `/\n\s+(\w{0,3})[\s&&[^\n]\S]+?([\d\.]+)[\S\s&&[^\n]]+?([\d\.]+)/`

If I understand ruby regular expressions correctly, `[\s&&[^\n]\S]` means that a character should be a whitespace character AND either a non-whitespace character or not a newline. As a character cannot be both a whitespace and non-whitespace character, you could probably shorten it to `[\s&&[^\n]]`.

You could also remove the parentheses, `(\w{0,3})` becomes `\w{0,3}`, but if you are trying to use the characters in those groups later on in your code, then you shouldn't.

- `/\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+-*\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+/`

You could combine some of your statements, `\s+\w+(\s+\d+){5}\s+-*(\s+\d+){2}\s+`, but again this would cause headaches if your code actually uses those groups to extract information.

Comment: I was even able to shorten it to [^\n]. It may be anything but a new line.

Comment: @DanAndreasson: It is because you make the group lazy. Otherwise, it will become a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Are you essentially aiming to split a fixed-width-column web page?

Regexp is one way. You may be interested in a fixed-width-column approach:

```
uri = URI.parse 'http://www.ida.liu.se/~TDP007/material/seminarie2/weather.txt'
page = uri.read
rows = page.split(/\n/)[9..-3]
rows.each{|r| 
  day, max, mnt = r[0..3].strip, r[4..11].strip, r[12..17].strip
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following might not be shorter (if you count the number of characters needed to type it), but it is a lot more readable:

```
arr  = ['(\w+)']     # Match a word
arr += ['(\d+)']*5   # Match five numbers
arr += ['-*']        # ignore dashes
arr += ['(\d+)']*2   # Match two numbers
# All of the above separated with space, plus space before and after.
my_regexp = Regexp.new(([''] + arr + ['']).join('\s+'))
```

Comment: Don't know, but this makes it harder for me to read... It may work for simple regex, but for complicated ones, it is harder to reason about it.

Comment: For me it's the opposite. I can read simple regexp:s, but once they start to fill a couple of lines my internal parser overflows... Splitting them into smaller groups makes them, for me, a lot easier to read.

Comment: Well, if the tokens are meaningful (semantic wise), then it is good (I did that to write some very long regex). In this case, it is not very meaningful semantically.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't `['(\d+)']*5` match an infinite number of characters, and cause catastrophic backtracking to boot? Perhaps you meant `['(\d)']*5`? Although `['(\d{5})']` would be a bit clearer.

Comment: I believe you missed the `join('\s+')` part. `'(\d+)'` will match a number with arbitrary number of digits. `['(\d+)']*5` will create an array of five such strings. The elements of the array is later joined with `\s+` as separator -- the end result is a regexp that is identical to the one in the original question (albeit much more readable).

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only file that you need to process then you can remove unnecessary data by hand, then read the file line by line, split by space characters `\s+` and pick out the columns.

Even without removing unnecessary data by hand, you can also read the original file line by line, split by `\s+`, and test whether the first few entries are numbers. This is exactly what you are doing with regex also (test format and extract data matching the format).

Note that `[\s&&[^\n]\S]` means intersecting `\s` and `[^\n]\S`, which results in the set: **all space characters** but new line. So we can rewrite it to `[\s&&[^\n]]`. However, `[\S\s&&[^\n]]` means intersecting `\S\s` and `[^\n]`, which results in the set: **all characters** but new line. The equivalent rewrite is `.` or `[^\n]`, but I doubt this is what you mean. The result will still be correct for the current input due to the lazy quantifier, but it might not for bad input.

Another thing is `.` will mean literal `.` inside character class, so `[\d.]` is equivalent to `[\d\.]`.